# How to disable chaining in Gmail for specific set of letters?

Tags: gmail

I'm sending some letters to subscribers, and they are chained in Gmail, since subject is the same.

The question is: how can I disable this feature **without** changing subject and **without** changing settings in Gmail interface?

Maybe there is specific header I can send, which is respected by Gmail?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've created a contact form in my website, which allows the user to send me an email. If I receive more than one message in one day, even from different senders, Gmail groups them in a thread. I'd love to disable this behaviour for this kind of messages, but so far, I didn't find a way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature isn't currently available, but Google has a [feature request page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py?contact_type=suggest) where you can suggest it.  I just did!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can turn the threading off selectively. From the Conversion view help page:

> A conversation will break off into a new thread if the subject line of
>   the conversation is changed, or if the conversation reaches over 100
>   messages.

If you're so inclined though, you can [turn off the Conversation view](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/turn-off-gmails-conversation-view.html) altogether. That way, you'd see your mail as individual messages.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great addition.

In the meantime, I had the issue using a contact form which had to show noreply@DOMAIN.com. I worked around it by adding the entered email address to the end of the subject field - different subject = new thread

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps. _What_ would be "a great addition"? Are you referring to another answer? Please note that this isn't a discussion forum, and that Answers can appear in lots of different orders. In fact, the default order isn't be date posted, but rather "score". If you want to refer to another answer, the best way is to link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a References header, like: `References: <TIMESTAMP@example>`